# Launching an EC2 Instance with an IAM Role Using Ansible

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible

I'm trying to [launch an instance with an IAM Role](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html) using [Ansible](http://docs.ansible.com/list_of_cloud_modules.html).

But I don't find how to do it.

Does anyone know if it is possible?

If I can't use Ansible. I try it with [boto](https://gist.github.com/garnaat/2917662)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

http://docs.ansible.com/ec2_module.html

> `instance_profile_name` *(added in 1.3)*:
>   Name of the IAM instance profile to use. Boto library must be 2.5.0+

Answer (score 2):

```
- name: Get Instance ID
  debug: var=ec2_id

- name: set IAM ROLE
  ec2_instance:
    region: eu-west-3
    aws_access_key: "{{ package_aws_access_key }}"
    aws_secret_key: "{{ package_aws_secret_key }}"  
    instance_ids:
        - "{{ ec2_id }}"
    instance_role: "{{ iam_role }}"
  delegate_to: localhost
```

Answer (score 0):

For `instance_profile_name` one simply has to use an IAM role name. 
If e.g. you have created an IAM role "webserver", then use "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:instance-profile/webserver" for `instance_profile_name` (edit arn to match your account).

make sure you also use the right trust policy principal:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": {
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Principal": {"Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com"},
    "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can test the tasks below and attach an `iam_role` to your instance.  I didn't try this with instance name but I think that it will work.

```
- name: Get Instance ID debug: 
   var=ec2_id

- name: set IAM ROLE 
  ec2_instance: 
    region: eu-west-3 
    aws_access_key: "{{ package_aws_access_key }}"
    aws_secret_key: "{{ package_aws_secret_key }}"
    instance_ids: 
      - "{{ ec2_id }}" 
    instance_role: "{{ iam_role }}" 
  delegate_to: localhost
```